# How to get order of intersection points that create and remove after moving an object in arrangement?

Tags: cgal

I want to get the sequence of events or intersection points that created and removed in the arrangement after moving a *circular object* form one position to another and I don't know how to do this using CGAL lib.

Comment: Hi Morteza, what have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use, what we refer to  as, observers; see the example program `examples/Arrangement_on_surface_2/observer.cpp` and the doc. at https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arr__observer.html

In particular, populate the following observer member functions

```
  after_create_vertex (Vertex_handle v)
  after_remove_vertex ()
```